# Working with Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: perl

I am working with an Excel worksheet to fetch two columns and replace file names based on them.

This is how I get the values of two columns that I am interested in. the 14th column could be a single value or more than one separated by a comma.

```
my @required = (2,14);
my @value;
my @files = grep{ -f && -T && -M > 0 } glob("$dir/*");
my @expected_file = grep{ /Parsed/ } @files;
print "@expected_file\n"; 
if(! $workbook)  {

     die $parser->error(),"\n";
}   


for my $row (1 .. $row_max) {

    @value = map{


        my $cell = $worksheets[0]->get_cell($row,$_);
        $cell ? $cell->value() : '';

    }@required;

  my %hash_value = @value;
  foreach my $key (keys %hash_value ){

      my @suffix = split /[, ]/,$hash_value{$key};

      push @{ $resample->{$key} },@suffix;


      print $key . ":" .@suffix,"\n";
  }   

 }
```

Output would be :

```
TY45745a:A,BTY45745a:C,DTY45745a:E,FTY5475a:G,HTY5475a:I,JTY5475a:K,L
```

Where TY45745a,TY5475a are the keys.What I would like to achieve is something like this : TY45745a A,B,C,D,E,F and TY5475a G,H,I,J,K,L.

And if the file names has [A-E] at the end of the file then it should be renamed to TY45745a[1..6], and if it has [G-L]  TY5475a[1..6].

Could this grouping of suffix for a name could be done when fetching from the Excel sheet?

How should I do this ? Any suggestions or pointers will be helpful .

Comment: The question doesn't really have anything to do with Spreadsheet::ParseExcel. It seems that you just need to translate the data that you are reading from the cells from one format to another. It might be better if you just stated the question in terms of the translation that you are trying to achieve and omit all the Excel code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your table looks like:

```
| B (2)    | N (14)  |
|:--------:|:-------:|
| TY45745a | A,B     |
| TY45745a | C,D     |
| TY45745a | E,F     |
| TY5475a  | G,H     |
| TY5475a  | I,J     |
| TY5475a  | K,L     |
```

You can do the first part

*Where TY45745a,TY5475a are the keys.What I would like to achieve is something like this : TY45745a A,B,C,D,E,F and TY5475a G,H,I,J,K,L.*

with the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Data::Dumper;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $book = $parser->Parse('Mappe1.xls') or die $parser->error(),"\n";
my $sheet = $book->{Worksheet};

my %hash;
for my $row (0 .. $sheet->[0]{MaxRow}) {

    my $c2 = $sheet->[0]->get_cell($row, 2-1);
    my $key = $c2 ? $c2->value() : '';

    my $c14 = $sheet->[0]->get_cell($row, 14-1);
    my @values = $c14 ? split(',', $c14->value()) : ();

    push @{$hash{$key}}, @values;
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

I added the missing parts to get the code running and simplified it a little
bit for demonstration purposes.