# Array to a hash perl

Tags: perl

It's the same thread with a different name as this ( [Working with Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297721/working-with-spreadsheetparseexcel) ). Since some of them suggested the title and the question didn't make sense. Sorry for not making it easy.

my question is : an array like this

```
TY45745a A,B
TY45745a C,D
TY45745a E,F
TY5475a G,H
TY5475a I,J
TY5475a K,L
```

should be made to a hash like this .

TY45745a =>(A,B,C,D,E,F)
TY5475a  =>(G,H,I,J,K,L)

And the next part of this would be to rename the file , And if the file names has [A-E] at the end of the file then it should be renamed to TY45745a[1..6], and if it has [G-L] TY5475a[1..6].

%hash = @array .

but that would result in

```
TY45745a => A,B
TY45745a => C,D
TY45745a => E,F
TY5475a =>  G,H
TY5475a =>  I,J
TY5475a =>  K,L
```

How should I group them ? Thanks for your time and suggestions

EDIT: Sorry, Bu that wouldn't work becos wen passed through the for loop the outpur of part would be like this:

```
TY45745a
A,B
TY45745a
C,D
TY45745a
E,F
TY5475a
G,H
TY5475a
I,J
TY5475a
K,L
```

Comment: Can you try to print the original array in a more legible fashion?

Comment: What are you talking about in your latest edit? Comments to answers belong under the answers you're commenting on. If you'd just print your array as it appears in your code, it would be a lot easier to help you. It' not clear if it's `('TY45745a', 'A,B', ...)` or `('TY45745a A,B', ...)`. Either way `%hash = @array` does not produce the output you describe.

Answer (score 2):

With the updated array in the question this works:

```
my $hash = {};

for my $part (@arr) {
    my ($key, $values) = split/ /, $part;
    push @{$hash->{$key}}, $_ for split/,/, $values;
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean about replacing [A-F] and [G-L] though, since this produces what you've described as your desired output without any replacements.

Comment: exactly what I was going to submit

Comment: @JoelBerger: I'll take that as a compliment. ;) Golfed version `map{push@{$hash->{shift@$_}},@$_}map{[split/[, ]/]}@arr;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use List::MoreUtils;
use Data::Dumper;

my $h; 
my @a = ("TY45745a", "A,B", 
         "TY45745a", "C,D", 
         "TY45745a", "E,F", 
         "TY5475a",  "G,H", 
         "TY5475a",  "I,J", 
         "TY5475a",  "K,L");

my $it = List::MoreUtils::natatime 2, @a; 

while (my ($k,$v) = $it->()) { 
    print "$k => $v"; 
    push @{$h->{$k}}, split /,/, $v; 
}; 

print Dumper($h)
```

gives:

```
TY45745a => A,B
TY45745a => C,D
TY45745a => E,F
TY5475a => G,H
TY5475a => I,J
TY5475a => K,L

$VAR1 = {
      'TY5475a' => [
                     'G',
                     'H',
                     'I',
                     'J',
                     'K',
                     'L'
                   ],
      'TY45745a' => [
                      'A',
                      'B',
                      'C',
                      'D',
                      'E',
                      'F'
                    ]
    };
```